# Word 2007 AddIn does not work with Word 2010

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, add-in, office-2010

I've written an add-in for Word 2007 in C#. To distribute the add-in I employed the ClickOnce installer. However, this add-in doesn't work with Word 2010. It produces the following error in the vsto.log file:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Word.Internal.IWordHostItemProviderProxy..ctor(IHostItemProviderExtendedContract hostItemProvider)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Word.Internal.IWordHostItemProviderProxy.GetProxy(IHostItemProviderExtendedContract contract)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Word.Internal.LocalWordServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Internal.LocalServiceProvider.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.EntryPointComponentBase.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.IEntryPoint.Initialize(IServiceProvider hostContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.AddInAdapter.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases executionPhases)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Internal.OfficeAddInAdapterBase.InitializeEntryPointsHelper()
```

While I understand that there is a version mismatch between the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word dll the add-in looks for and the one available on the system with Word 2010, I have no idea how I could fix this issue. I did some Google searching but nothing interesting came up. Please help.

Comment: What version of VSTO and .NET are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to trace down the problem in the end. Sorry for not posting about it sooner. It seems I was linking to the wrong libraries instead of the PIA ones which caused this problem. The problem was fixed after making the change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to turn off the specific Version check for those word assemblies in the click once install project.

Answer (score 0):

First Check PIA(primary Interop Assembly) is installed in your system using below code

```
   bool IsPrimaryInteropAssembliesInstalled()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Assembly.Load("Policy.11.0.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c") != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then download office PIA from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18346. and run below code

```
void InstallPrimaryInteropAssemblies()
    {
        try
        {
            string str = "path\o2007pia.msi";
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
            {
                StartInfo = { FileName = str }
            };
            process.Start();
            while (!process.HasExited)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0x3e8);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }
    }
```